# What will happen if we try to handle one type of exception with a different type of exception class and why?

Tags: java, oop

```
public class TryCatchExample8 {  

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    try  
    {  
    int data=50/0; //may throw exception   

    }  
        // try to handle the ArithmeticException using ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)  
    {  
        System.out.println(e);  
    }  
    System.out.println("rest of the code");  
}  
}
```

*I got this code from a website. They handled the generated exception (Arithmetic Exception) with a different type of exception class (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException).
It's showing this in the output,*

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
> at TryCatchExample8.main(TryCatchExample8.java:6)".

*How is it showing this if we tried to catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?*

Comment: The first thing you can do is to try it. That would give you some useful information that you can use to dig deeper.

Comment: If your question is "what does this code do", it would have been faster to run it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Since both of these exception are RuntimeException there is no control at compilation time that the caught exception can actually be raised.

In this case, the code will not catch the ArithmeticException at all, so there will be no output to this program, since all prints are in the catch or after the  exception is thrown (and not caught).

Comment: But it's showing this in the output, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
 at TryCatchExample8.main(TryCatchExample8.java:6)". How it's doing this if we tried to catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: @Yann TM is right. Your code did not handles the exception, the java virtual machine 'did' it instead. Actually, the exception was unhandled...

Comment: uncaught exceptions that go out of the main method produce an (error) output. This is what you are seeing, the exception was not caught since it is not "instanceof ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" which is how the catch clause works (testing instanceof)

Comment: in other words, you would get exactly the same result if you remove the try catch in your code. It's not doing anything.